# Ajax form submission progress function failing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm submitting a form via ajax and trying to update a simple progress bar while it's uploading. The form submission works perfectly but I can't get the progress bar to update or even request the currently loaded amount.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">          
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <button>Update Account</button>
</form>
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

**jQuery + Ajax**

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(){

    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname,
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        async:false,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Upon submitting the form should run `addEventListener` so that this function is run to update the progress:

```
function progressHandlingFunction(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){
        $("progress").attr('value', e.loaded);
        $("progress").attr('max', e.total);
    }
}
```

but any functions inside `myXhr.upload.addEventListener();` just do not seem to run?

```
myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', alert("test"),  false);
```

works fine, but the below does not run, why would this happen?:

```
myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(){alert("test")},  false);
```

This example uses similar coding:

http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was:

```
async:false,
```

Removing that solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).live("submit", "form", function(){
```

Should be:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(){
```

Or even better:

```
$("#static-container-Id").on("submit", "form", function(){
```

If you want to use `live` (jQuery < 1.4.4)

```
$("form").live("submit", function(){
```

Comment: Ah yes I meant to use `.on`, problem still persists though.

Comment: @Silver89. Well, so here you got one problem solved. I'm afraid I must go off key-board of a while. I hope you will answers to the other problems as well. Good Luck!